# How to access Generated WPF controls after Data Binding

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, datatemplate

Please consider the following XAML code:

```
<ListBox Name="listBox1" ItemsSource="{Binding}" >
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border Name="border1">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

and we assign a simple array to it:

```
listBox1.DataContext = new[] { "A", "B", "C" };
```

Now the question is how we can access the **generated objects for Border** (or TextBlock instances)?

- It is not possible by "border1". It does not exist.
- `listBox1.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(0)` returns a ListBoxItem but content of that ListBoxItem is of type String.
- `FindName("border1")` returns null

Update: What I expect to find are **3** instances of Border (and 3 TextBlocks, one in each Border).

Answer (score 2):

Once you get the ListBoxItem, you need to walk the visual tree to find what your looking for.

Dr WPF has some great articles about it [here](http://drwpf.com/blog/2008/07/20/itemscontrol-g-is-for-generator/)

Here is the code from that article to search for a descendant of a particular type

```
  public static Visual GetDescendantByType(Visual element, Type type)
  {
      if (element.GetType() == type) return element;

      Visual foundElement = null;

      if (element is FrameworkElement)
          (element as FrameworkElement).ApplyTemplate();

      for (int i = 0;
          i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(element); i++)
      {
          Visual visual = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(element, i) as Visual;
          foundElement = GetDescendantByType(visual, type);
          if (foundElement != null)
              break;
      }

      return foundElement;
  }
```

Comment: However, I just wanted to point out Dr. WPF also states that manipulating the visual tree in this manner should rarely be needed. There are much more 'correct' (reliable and/or resilient) ways of doing just about anything.

Comment: Unfortunately this cannot be the answer: What I am looking for are "instances" or Border when they are generated not the one that is inside ItemTemplate. Here I expect to find "3" objects of type Border (I have 3 items in DataContext)

Comment: @shayan: Walking the visual tree will get you the instance data you want.  Just use the listview as the Visual and Border as the type.  But like Alex suggested, their generally is a better approach.  What are you trying to do with the Border when you get it?

Comment: This question was actually raised as a solution to the situation that is explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802102/animating-this-and-other-in-wpf

Answer (score 0):

You can access it like so:

```
        DataTemplate dt = this.listBox1.ItemTemplate;
        Border border = dt.LoadContent() as Border;
        // Do something with border...
```